# The first visit to any site takes forever to load

Tags: linux, firefox, dns, fedora

I suspect I might have a DNS problem.

Whenever I try to access any website at all, it will take dozens of seconds to load in the first time. Any subsequent access will load just fine.

If I try to `ping` a non-visited web address, it will hang for a few seconds before displaying the normal output.

[image]

How can I troubleshoot my DNS issues?

Comment: Have you tried using other DNS servers?  You can get a list of free and public DNS servers [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm)

Comment: Do you have a non-working IPv6 address assigned to your box, and a DNS server that's returning AAAA records? If so, your OS might be trying to access the IPv6 address of the site. Of course, this whole theory falls flat if you are trying to access sites which have **no** AAAA record and still see this delay...

Comment: I *had* tried other DNS servers, but turns out my organization blocks the Google DNS servers. I tried different DNS servers and it is blazing fast now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing DNS servers solved the issue.

A great way to benchmark DNS server performances is using [the DNS Benchmark by Steve Gibson](https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm), it tests the performance of your current DNS servers and a up-to-date list of publicly available servers as well.

[image]